# python scrapy code not giving any output

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, scrapy

I am trying to run the code using python(scrapy) but there is no output.
I am also tyring to login to a webpage, let me know if there are any errors

The code i am using is this:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    def init(self, login, password):
        link = "http://freeerisa.benefitspro.com"
        self.login = login
        self.password = password
        self.cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(
            urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
            urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
            urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
            urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)
        )
        self.loginToFreeErissa()
        self.loginToFreeErissa()
    def loginToFreeErissa(self):
        login_data = urllib.urlencode({
            'MainContent_mainContent_txtEmail' : self.login,
            'MainContent_mainContent_txtPassword' : self.password,
         })
        response = self.opener.open(link + "/login.aspx", login_data)
        return ''.join(response.readlines())
    def after_login(self, response):
        if "Error while logging in" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed!")
        else:
            url = [link + "/5500/plandetails.aspx?Ein=042088633",
                link + "/5500/plandetails.aspx?Ein=046394579"]
            for u in url:
                g_data =soup.find_all("span")
                for item in g_data:
                    return item.text
```

I tried calling the function and this is the error I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders_init_.py",line 30, 
in init raise ValueError("%s must have a name" % type(self).__name__) 
ValueError: MySpider must have a name
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no output because you don't call anything.

In other worlds, you defined what is **MySpider** but you didn't used it.

Here's [a link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) that could help you

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I did try calling the function and this is the error I received: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 30, in __init__
    raise ValueError("%s must have a name" % type(self).__name__)
ValueError: MySpider must have a name

Comment: If it's the first time you do Python programs, you should try to learn on simpler exemples.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    def init(self, login, password):
        link = "http://freeerisa.benefitspro.com"
```

and run your spider by

```
scrapy crawl myspider
```

for [**more information**](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html)

Answer (score -1):

The error message could not be plainer: **The spider must have a name**. There is no name in the code you have posted. This is *basic* to creating a spider in Scrapy. Also, your Python spacing is terrible, you need an editor with Pylint or something that will tell you about PEP8.